# Default trace writer in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, logging, asp.net-web-api

According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj129375%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)  :

> Use the `ITraceWriter` interface to write traces for ASP.NET Web API.
>   The default implementation of `ITraceWriter` is a “no-op” tracer

Why do I get `null` in my application?

```
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            ITraceWriter trace = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetTraceWriter();
            //..........
        }
    }
```

I need the instance to pass as a dependency to my handlers/etc. Sure, I can implement and register 'no-op' writer myself but...

And why would I prefer that new interface over good old `System.Diagnostics` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web API has a Tracing nuget package called `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing`, which you can use to get the default System.Diagnostic tracing.

You can then do:

```
config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Testing and Debugging](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api).
You get `null` because the tracer is not in a pipeline.

You can replace default tracer by your implementation:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   config.Services.Replace(typeof(ITraceWriter), new SimpleTracer());
}
```